# Set a data value for a content field with rules

Tags: rules

I am able to create a new content with rules whenever a user has been flagged as 'satisfied'. However, i need to fill in the fields as well with the flagged username, and some other fields in the flagged user profile. This i tried to do with 'set a data value' but the parameters doesn't seem to be available. Only 'site' and 'node' is available in d data selection field.
Is there a way to 'fetch' the user profile of the flagged user and use it in the fields of the newly created contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself.

under the same rule (after a user has been flagged, )and after "create a new entity", I added 'set a data value' and chose 'entity-created:'. This then followed by the value "flagged-user:...".

If you understand my question, then you should understand my answer.lols

Comment: I think you should mark your own answer as accepted, so that it no longer shows as "unanswered".